# HTML project in netbeans

Tags: php, javascript, html, netbeans

Ok I just installed netbeans for php and i'm trying to create a new project for html/javascript but I only see php project there.

I can create a php project and just create html files inside of it, but it makes me define a project path to localhost. So when I try to run my project, it directs to localhost instead of my project's root folder.

Sorry I'm new to this piece of software so excuse any ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It redirects because php requires a server. If you have plan to make a project for html and javascript alone you can try with some good html editors like dreamweaver or other IDE's.